# Simple C Program

Tags: c, lexical-analysis, kernighan-and-ritchie

This program is based on the program in K&R in the input/output section

```
#include <stdio.h>


 main(){

double sum, v;

sum = 0;

while (scanf("%1f",&v)==1)
    printf("\t%.2f\n",sum+=v);
return 0;
}
```

It compiles ok. But when trying to run, from any input the output is "-NAN", presumably NOT A NUMBER. I have no idea why. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems I may have fixed it by changing double to float. Which makes sense, since the input and output are floats. But in K&R they use double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format code is wrong in scanf.  It should be `%lf` (with lower case L), not `%1f`.

```
 while (scanf("%lf",&v)==1)
```

This is because `%lf` scans for a double, and `%f` scans for a float. For details, see [scanf format codes](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html).

Comment: +1 for an excellent catch. While my answer would work, yours is "more correct"

Comment: I'm sure it was just a mis-read, given how close "1" and "l" look in text.

Comment: Thanks. That's what happens when you mindlessly copy code. But if I use "lf", it still gives -NAN if sum and v are floats. It only works if they are double. Do you know why?

Comment: Because "%lf" is for double values and "%f" for floats. See the documentation for format codes http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

Comment: @JJG scanf (and printf) are varargs functions so they don't know the types of their arguments; they must manually pluck them off the stack. Since floats and doubles have different sizes, passing a float when a double is expected or v.v. results in garbage -- which will often be interpreted as NAN.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the double to a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%1f",&v)
```

You reading a float, but your variable is a double. Try:

```
scanf("%lf",&v)
```